# Remove index.php from Hard Coded HTML site

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I coded a site from the ground top with the index file names as index.php.

The site is live, but each time I go to my homepage, I see domain.com/index.php

I need a solution so that everytime I visit my homepage I see only domain.com and not domain.com/index.php.

So far the solutions I have seen here are stripping just the .php part, anyone out there with a solution that will enable me see my homepage as domain.com and not domain.com/index.php should help me out.

Comment: You will need a rewrite rule. Are you using apache or nginx?

Comment: @JairusMartin I am using Apache

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Apache` use the below code in your `.htaccess` file. If you dont have a `.htaccess`  file, create one in root.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

If you are using `Nginx`, use below rewrite in the top level server clause in `Nginx` conf file.

```
rewrite ^(.*)/index.php$ $1 permanent;

location = /index.php{
  rewrite  ^ / permanent;
  try_files /index.php=404;
}
```

The =404 part returns a 404 error when the file is not found.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DirectoryIndex index.php` to set `index.php` as root file and redirect every request to `index.php` to root.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://example.com/ [QSA,L,R=301]
```